# hook task for other specific Rake tasks

Tags: ruby, rake

I want to execute hook task before and after specific Rake tasks.
So, I tried to use Task#enhance for invoking hook task.
However, the hook task runs only on the fist specific task.
As an workaround, I added Task#reenable in the block of Task#enhance as below.

```
task :task_1 => [:depending_task_1, :depending_task_2] do
  puts "executing 1..."
end

task :task_2 => [:depending_task_3] do
  puts "executing 2..."
end

task :task_3 do
  puts "executing 3..."
end

task :task_4 do
  puts "executing 3..."
end

task :task_all => [:task_1, :task_2, :task_3, :task_4] do
end

task :before_hook do
  puts 'running before_hook...'
end

task :after_hook do
  puts 'running after_hook...'
end

tasks_which_has_hook_tasks = [:task_1, :task_2, :task_3]

tasks_which_has_hook_tasks.each do |t|
  Rake::Task[t].enhance([:before_hook]) do
    Rake::Task[:after_hook].invoke

    Rake::Task[:before_hook].reenable
    Rake::Task[:after_hook].reenable
  end
end
```

This looks like verbose code(because of using reenable).
Is there any other reasonable way?

I expect following result for :task_all

```
(step 1) :before_hook
(step 2) :depending_task_1
(step 3) :depending_task_2
(step 4) :task_1
(step 5) :after_hook
(step 6) :before_hook
(step 7) :depending_task_3
(step 8) :task_2
(step 9) :after_hook
(step 10) :before_hook
(step 11) :task_3
(step 12) :after_hook
(step 13) :task_4
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's really verbose, you can shorten it the following way.

```
task :one do
 #Do something...
end

task :two do
 #Do some other thing...
end

task :three do
 #Do one final thing...
end
```

Then, you can create the task that will only run when the required tasks did what they needed to do.

```
task :final_task => [:one,:two,:three] do
 #This will run when the three required tasks end...
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and sorry for lacking of information. I added some information and example for more detail about this question.

Comment: Well, in that case I can only think about grouping tasks and writing a long line for :task_all 

    task :task_all => [ :before_hook, :task_1, :after_before_hook_task, :task_2, :after_before_hook_2_task, :task_3, :after_hook, :task_4 ]

I know it's kinda bulky but right now I can't figure another way to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I think this code can be sophisticated if task objects have something like an attribute which means automatically re-enabling the task. hmm..